# convertir fila a columnas sql server

Tags: sql, server

Tengo la  siguiente  tabla maestro detalle. Donde  tiene  las  columnas iddetalle, idanalisis, idexamen, nomexamen, precio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que  quiero  hacer pasar los datos de la columna nomexamen  como columnas es decir si el idanalisis es  14 que liste todos los nomexamen que  tiene  pero como  columnas asi mismo  con los  idanalisis 12,13,15 y  como en la  siguiente imagen  creo quese puede entender  mejor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la  verdad desconozco si hay alguna consulta  en sql  server para  hacerlo. lo mas  que he podido es con  el pivot y medio esto  como resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El escenario que planteas:

```
Create Table dbo.detalle_examen
             (
             iddetalle_examen Int
           , idanalisis       Int
           , idexamen         Int
           , nomexamen        VarChar(100)
           , precio           Decimal(6, 2)
             );
Go
Insert into dbo.detalle_examen (iddetalle_examen, idanalisis, idexamen, nomexamen, precio)
values
(5, 12,1,'Citometría hemática completa',356.00),
(6, 13,2,'Reticulocitos',               345.00),
(7, 14,1,'Citometría hemática completa',356.00),
(8, 14,2,'Reticulocitos',               345.00),
(9, 14,3,'Plaquetas',                   564.00),
(10,14,4,'Grupo Sanguíneo y factor Rh', 234.00),
(11,14,5,'VSG(velocidad de sed. glob.)',123.00),
(12,14,6,'Coombs directo',              231.00),
(13,14,7,'Coombs indirecto',            489.00),
(14,14,9,'Folatos',                     111.00),
(15,14,8,'Vitamina B12',                234.00),
(16,14,10,'Perfil de hierro sérico',    383.00),
(17,14,11,'Ferritina',                  235.00),
(18,14,14,'Saturación',                 234.00),
(19,15,1,'Citometría hemática completa',356.00),
(20,15,2,'Reticulocitos',               356.00),
(21,16,1,'Citometría hemática completa',356.00),
(22,16,2,'Reticulocitos',               345.00),
(23,16,3,'Plaquetas',                   564.00);
GO
```

Una de las posibles soluciones es numerar las filas, particionando por idAnalisis, de manera que cuando este cambia se reinicia la numeración.

**Nota**: te voy a ir mostrando cada parte sola, para tener al final la consulta completa.

```
With r
     As (Select detalle_examen.iddetalle_examen
              , detalle_examen.idanalisis
              , detalle_examen.idexamen
              , detalle_examen.nomexamen
              , detalle_examen.precio
              , Row_Number() Over(Partition By idanalisis
                Order By idexamen
                       , idanalisis) As row
                From dbo.detalle_examen)
Select * from r
```

[image: Salida 1]

Como se ve en la imagen, por cada idanalisis, se inicia la numeración.

Ahora con las filas numeradas, podemos hacer un case para cada una de ellas y evaluar si la columna row es igual al número de columna elegido mostramos nomExamen.

```
With r
     As (Select detalle_examen.iddetalle_examen
              , detalle_examen.idanalisis
              , detalle_examen.idexamen
              , detalle_examen.nomexamen
              , detalle_examen.precio
              , Row_Number() Over(Partition By idanalisis
                Order By idexamen
                       , idanalisis) As row
                From dbo.detalle_examen)
    , r2
     As (Select idanalisis
              , Case
                    When row = 1 Then nomexamen
                End As examen1
              , Case
                    When row = 2 Then nomexamen
                End As examen2
              , Case
                    When row = 3 Then nomexamen
                End As examen3
              , Case
                    When row = 4 Then nomexamen
                End As examen4
              , Case
                    When row = 5 Then nomexamen
                End As examen5
              , Case
                    When row = 6 Then nomexamen
                End As examen6
              , Case
                    When row = 7 Then nomexamen
                End As examen7
              , Case
                    When row = 8 Then nomexamen
                End As examen8
              , Case
                    When row = 9 Then nomexamen
                End As examen9
                From r)
Select * from r2
```

[image: Salida 2]

Ya tenemos el resultado esperado, pero ahora tendremos que agrupar las filas, para que por cada idanalisis se muestre una sola fila.

```
 With r
     As (Select detalle_examen.iddetalle_examen
              , detalle_examen.idanalisis
              , detalle_examen.idexamen
              , detalle_examen.nomexamen
              , detalle_examen.precio
              , Row_Number() Over(Partition By idanalisis
                Order By idexamen
                       , idanalisis) As row
                From dbo.detalle_examen)
    , r2
     As (Select idanalisis
            , Case When row = 1 Then nomexamen End As examen1
            , Case When row = 2 Then nomexamen End As examen2
            , Case When row = 3 Then nomexamen End As examen3
            , Case When row = 4 Then nomexamen End As examen4
            , Case When row = 5 Then nomexamen End As examen5
            , Case When row = 6 Then nomexamen End As examen6
            , Case When row = 7 Then nomexamen End As examen7
            , Case When row = 8 Then nomexamen End As examen8
            , Case When row = 9 Then nomexamen End As examen9
            , Case When row = 10 Then nomexamen End As examen10
            , Case When row = 11 Then nomexamen End As examen11
            , Case When row = 12 Then nomexamen End As examen12
        From r)
     Select r2.idanalisis
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen1),'') As examen1
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen2),'') As examen2
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen3),'') As examen3
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen4),'') As examen4
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen5),'') As examen5
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen6),'') As examen6
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen7),'') As examen7
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen8),'') As examen8
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen9),'') As examen9
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen10),'') As examen10
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen11),'') As examen11
          , isnull(Max(r2.examen12),'') As examen12
            From r2
    group by idanalisis;
```

[image: Resultado 3]

Esta podría ser una solución.

[Cte,s. Correlativos](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

[Numerar filas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)

Comment: muchas gracias  por  su ayuda me  sirvio  de  mucho y esta bien explicado